# Lyx: Choose option from .cls file

Tags: lyx, acm, options, layout

I would like to use the ***sigconf*** style from [***acmart.cls***](http://www.sigplan.org/sites/default/files/acmart/current/acmart.cls).

I have already downloaded the *acmart.cls* file into the latex folder, run *texhash* and copied a minimal .layout file:

```
#% Do not delete the line below; configure depends on this
\DeclareLaTeXClass[acmart]{ACM_sigconf}

# Input general definitions
Input stdclass.inc
```

Then reconfigured Lyx (version 2.0.8.1) and chosen the new document class in the document settings.

However, upon PDF creation, it chooses the wrong option for my purpose, probably *acmlarge*.

How can I tell Lyx to choose option *sigconf* instead?

Comment: the first line of your tex file should be \documentclass[format=sigconf]{acmart} that declaration should then be followed by everything else  for support on acmart you can follow the guidance at https://www.acm.org/publications/authors/submissions  the key to a good working class is that you installed the package with either tex live manager or MiKTeX-console they then configure the files into the correct locations for the class file to operate as directed by you and the editor

Comment: @KJO This is a LyX question not a pure LaTeX question so although your comment  is helpful for LaTeX it doesn't address the question at hand.

Comment: @AlanMunn OK have changed the comment to an answer i.e. change the class format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct class file is essential to control the pdf output so when you start an acmart document using lyx it adds this first line by default

```
\documentclass[english,format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}
```

[image]

Thus you desire to change the format so replace acmsmall with sigconf

Comment: Looks good! Any idea why the abstract won't show in the PDF?

Comment: sorry don't use LyX so haven't a clue what it does with the files, as a seperate question you could post the relavent lines of tex code and someone may see if there is a conflict for something like abstract in LyX it helps non lyx users to see a mini screen shot of either the result  or work in progress or the settings gui to understand why LyX settings are different to plain lines of code

Comment: Yeah no worries, I only use lyx for the first versions. The final publication I finish in tex. I'll just enter a section as an abstract to get approximate space consumption.

Comment: looking at the abstract section it needs a valid coded cut and paste from the website so would need a suitable clipboard chunk of output . However it looks like the abstact has to be manually cut and pasted too where it say abstract here !

Comment: P.S. re your query about abstract I was looking at another issue and reminded your problem could be due to placement of abstract in that template see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385029/abstract-does-not-appear-with-acmart-latex-template

Comment: Perfect! I copied the abstract with ``\begin{abstract}`` and ``\end{abstract}`` around it into the document header under document->settings and now it is displayed.